# Frigidaire refrigerator: no ice produced, and no water dispensed. What would cause this besides the 3-way water valve?

Tags: refrigerator, ice-maker

FFHS2311LBSA side-by-side fridge with water dispenser.  Water is not dispensed, and no ice is produced.  Common wisdom says the water valve assembly (3 valves, 3 solenoids) is the most likely culprit but I measure ~400 ohms across each coil.  In addition, when the water dispenser paddle is depressed, I get 120V across one of the solenoids.

I assume the water runs from the main valve to the filter, then back to the valve assembly, where either the dispenser or icemaker pulls a solenoid to deliver water.  This would mean that the main solenoid would have to energize AND also one of the other valves to deliver water. I never see 120v across the main solenoid (when I depress the dispenser paddle).

I could replace the water valve assembly as a shotgun guess but my gut is telling me it's something else. If I'm right about how the valves work, how does the water dispenser send 120V to both the main and the dispenser solenoids? And why would it send 120v to only one of them?

thanks for any help!

Comment: Follow up question: Anyone know where I can get a READABLE wiring diagram for this? Looks like the icemaker and dispenser trigger wires both go to one side of the main valve through diodes...?  Looks like there is an 'Ice & water control board' but it's so hard to read this low-res JPG! Where would the I&W control board be located?

Comment: Before you dig too deep, measure the fridge temperature. I had a similar issue it was a bad thermostat that caused the water line to freeze.

Comment: Are you sure the filter isn't clogged?

Comment: Is this a model with a filter? I have had trouble with the valve not opening with even name brand filters Finnaly made a shim out of poly propylene and never had any more problems, I was going after electrical because of the intermittent problems more not working than working since getting the shim the right size it has worked for close to a year. (The first 2 times it was under warranty my wife said she did not know what he did, maybe cycle the valves I don't know but it was inside the fridge)

Comment: Is the output of the water (that flows into the ice maker) blocked with ice?  A slow flowing source (blocked line, filter etc) will dribble water into the ice maker slowly enough that it can ice up. (This might depend on your specific fridge's design)

Comment: Supply failure is one option, but seems like starting with a good old-fashioned manual defrost (shift stuff into coolers, open it up, and let it sit with the power off) would be the place to start.

Comment: Unhook your water line and ensure water is getting to the fridge valve. Then unhook the water line from the output side of the solenoid that "works" and make sure it will allow water to flow through it. Check your filter also if it has one. They need to be inserted completely (twisted if needed.) Make your way from one section verifying water flows until you find the culprit.

Comment: I downloaded the schematics, and it looks like the dispenser solenoid line should also trigger the main valve because it's connected through a 'diode assembly'.  I am assuming that if I jumper out the diode I should be able to pull both the main and dispenser valves and check water flow. Surely the main valve would open if I put 120VAC directly across it...

Comment: I've had this happen more than once. You waited too long to change the filter, the slower water flow allowed ice to build up in the line. Once it freezes solid, it becomes self perpetuating and the ice plug grows backward until it reaches the line feeding the ice maker. I have to get access to the water lines and hit them with a hair drier. You can also let it melt naturally by unplugging the fridge and waiting, but it took two days for that when I tried it. They are very well insulated.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to close this out:  turns out the problem was the filter, presumably clogged (over two years old).  Thanks to @mike65535, who hit the nail on the head right off the bat. Did not try this first because I did not have a spare filter on hand...