# No water and ice in refrigerator, how to fix it when filter is not the issue?

Tags: water, refrigerator, filter, ice-maker

My question is very similar to [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/147669/frigidaire-refrigerator-no-ice-produced-and-no-water-dispensed-what-would-cau) but I have bypass filter, meaning I don't have a filter.

I know filter is the most common reason when there is no water in refrigerator and hence no ice as well. What should I look for now since my refrigerator was setup to bypass filter?

Comment: Have you checked the water supply line and valve to see if water is getting to the fridge ?

Comment: @AlaskaMan Not really but can't think why water supply would have been compromised. But do you mean the supply valve at the back of the refrigerator? How do even check it?

Comment: The supply is often from a cheap little valve that can fail by leaking (really bad) or by clogging (no water and ice, but no mess either). You need to: turn off water supply (at main cutoff if necessary), disconnect tubing from valve at the refrigerator and turn back on and see if you get water. If you get water flow then the problem is in the refrigerator. If you don't get water flow then the problem is a connection in your plumbing somewhere - usually only one or two places that it can be.

Comment: The water has to come from somewhere and there should be a valve where it branches off of another line. It could be under the sink or in the crawl space of your house. you will have find it. There are reasons why the supply could be comprised like a blockage in the line or ?? The point is you need to determine if it is a supply issue or a problem with the fridge itself  in order to know how to proceed. Find the valve turn it off, disconnect the line and then slowly turn on the valve a little to see if water comes out. next, with valve off disconnect the line to see if you can blow through it.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Thanks, I believe this line is at the back of refrigerator right? My refrigerator is so tightly squeezed into the space,I was hoping to avoid pulling it out but I guess that's must.